# ISO 8583 response when client not previously initialize with 0800

Tags: iso8583

My question mainly will be related to ISO8583 for MTI "0800" regarding "logon request".

The question is, what if the client did not initialize with "0800" previously? So he just sends a message with MTI other than "0800".

For instance, if the client sent "0200", but not yet send "0800" previously, how we should tell him that he must do "0800" first:

- Should it be using the same ISO8583 message class from the request?. For instance, when user send a message with MTI "0200", but because he did not logon previously with "0800", we give response "0220"
- Or should it use "08xx" MTI response for every request sent by the user when they did not initialize a "logon request"?. For instance, even user sent MTI "0200", we will still give them "0820" instead "0210" because he did not login yet.

I am sorry if maybe my question does not make sense, I just a few days working with ISO8583. I hope someone can help me answer my question with a general practice or even best practice of ISO8583, or just please correcting me :).

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a 0800, you should expect a 0810 in response.
If, on the other hand, you receive a 0800, you should reply with a 0810.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, however, my point, Is it make sense if the client sent "0200" but because he did not "0800" ( network logon ) initially, instead send "0210" or any "02xx" we send them "0810" or "0820" as response? Or should we still send "02xx" to tell the client that they need to do login first with "0800"? I update my question with some fixes which may lead to confusion.

Comment: At 0X00 Request will always expect and 0X10 response. (of course as always, it's conceivable that there is some messaed up 8583 setup somewhere doing something weird, so consult the manual of your dialect, but this seems pretty cut and dry to me)

Comment: If you really need a 0800 logon message first, just because your system operates that way, you can answer the 0200 with a 0210 and a result code indicating a session error, but logon stuff was usually related to old mainframe sessions, you don't use them in regular POS transactions.

Comment: if we not dealing with logon, do you mean POS transaction doesn't have a security mechanism related to authentication/logon? Or it should get achieved by another way such as white list IP?